# IOS/Objective-C: How to Access JSON within parentheses

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am used to seeing brackets in JSON but am thrown off by parentheses which unless I'm missing something are not part of the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org).

The temp value in the following JSON response from an API within brackets can be accessed as shown:

```
JSON:
main =     {
        humidity = 25;
        pressure = 1013;
        temp = "79.7";
        "temp_max" = "91.04000000000001";
        "temp_min" = "66.92";
    };

NSNumber *temp = jsonResults[@"main"][@"temp"]; //returns the temp
```

Given that, what would syntax be to access 'main' in the following:

```
weather =     (
                {
            description = "clear sky";
            icon = 01d;
            id = 800;
            main = Clear;
        }
    );
```

Nothing I have tried has worked.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: `weather` is showing an array of dictionary. BTW - that's not JSON you are showing. That' the output of printing `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
NSArray*weather = jsonResults[@"weather"];
NSString*main = weather[0][@"main"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *main = [weather valueforkey:@"main"];
```